# HTML5 Canvas - Draw segments and circles - Different color for one circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I try to draw circles joined by segments. I want the segments to have black color and the circles blue color except for the first circle (which is at the center of canvas and must be black).

Here's a capture showing the current result :

[image]

As you can see, the result is good except for the first circle which remains blue.

Here's the code :

```
// Get context
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.fillStyle = 'white';
context.fillRect(0, 0, 650, 650);

// Draw black segments
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(x0, y0);
context.lineTo(x1, y1);
context.lineTo(x2, y2);
context.lineTo(x3, y3);
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();

// Draw circles (blue except for the first which is black)
context.beginPath();
// Create sub-path
context.moveTo(x0, y0);
context.arc(x0, y0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fill();
context.closePath();
// Close sub-path

// Create sub-path
context.moveTo(x1, y1);
context.arc(x1, y1, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.closePath();
// Close sub-path

// Create sub-path
context.moveTo(x2, y2);
context.arc(x2, y2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.closePath();
// Close sub-path

// Create sub-path
context.moveTo(x3, y3);
context.arc(x3, y3, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.closePath();
// Close sub-path

// Fill all sub-paths
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.fill();
```

It seems that I can't fill only one circle by putting :

```
    context.beginPath();
    // Create sub-path
    context.moveTo(x0, y0);
    context.arc(x0, y0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
    // Close sub-path
```

If someone could see what's wrong to circumvent this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to begin a new path to fill in your blue circles

```
context.beginPath();
//draw black circle
context.fill();

context.beginPath();
//draw blue arcs
context.fillStyle='blue
context.fill();
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/o6vyf9nf/1/)

Comment: Thanks but I get another issue if I put grey instead of black, you can see that it draws a little segment between the center of first circle and its edge : https://jsfiddle.net/3ouLju43/

Comment: i'm learning this too :) You need to begin the path after you move: See line 23-24 here:https://jsfiddle.net/3ouLju43/1/